# Room Kotlin:Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

When I run my app,I got follow error.

```
Error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty
  constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
  Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
  ChatMsg(java.lang.String,int) : [arg0 : null, arg1 : null]
Error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty
  constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
Error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty
  constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
  Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
  ChatMsg(java.lang.String,int) : [arg0 : null, arg1 : null]
Error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty
  constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
Warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
```

That's my build.gradle for project

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()  
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.letv.sarrsdesktop:BlockCanaryExPlugin:0.9.9.2'

    }
}   
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

That's my build.gradle for module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cn.sz.cyrus.kotlintest"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions{
            annotationProcessorOptions{
                includeCompileClasspath = true
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
    compile 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.5'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.15'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.umeng.analytics:analytics:latest.integration'
    compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:1.7.0' //for Android
    compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-rxjava:1.7.0' //for RxJava support
    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha3"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha3"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha3"
    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-alpha3" 
}
```

That's my pojo class

```
@Entity
data class ChatMsg(var msg: String,
              var to: Int) {

    companion object TO {
        val MASTER = 0
        val ROBOT = 1
    }

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
    var createTime: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var translMsg: String = ""
}
```

I have google my problem,but results seems can't answer my question.Who has ideas for this question . Thanks for first!

Comment: what are the `msg` and `to` in the constructor do you use them as columns in the table or it's supposed to be `id`, `createTime` and `translMsg`?

Comment: @OlegOsipenko The msg field means the main content about ChatMsg . 
The to field means ChatMsg sent to and its value is MASTER or ROBOT. I need to use all those fields as columns in the table.

Comment: so only two columns? But I see an `id` with `@PrimaryKey` annotation, so I think it's also a column

Comment: I remember all fields would be taken as column  except I add @Ingore annotation to those fields .

Comment: so it's already answered: you have explanation in the stacktrace, basically either make an empty constructor with empty parameters or pass all the fields to the constructor. `You can have an empty
  constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message said exactly:

> You can have an **empty
>     constructor** or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by **name and type**).

One thing should be noted. You should be using [Annotation Site Target](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) to put the `@PrimaryKey` into the correct place.

so your entity should have an empty constructor:

```
@Entity
data class ChatMsg(var msg: String, var to: Int) {
    constructor() : this("", UNKNOWN);

    companion object TO {
        val MASTER = 0
        val ROBOT = 1
        private val UNKNOWN = -1; // just use for initializing
    }

    @field: PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
}
```

**OR** should have a constructor that matches the fields.

```
@Entity
data class ChatMsg(
        @field:PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int, 
        var createTime: Long = System.currentTimeMillis(),
        var translMsg: String = "", 
        var msg: String, var to: Int
) {

    companion object TO {
        val MASTER = 0
        val ROBOT = 1
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . My problem has been solved.

Comment: @Cyrus Not at all.

Comment: On more question, NOTE: On the JVM, if all of the parameters of the primary constructor have default values, the compiler will generate an additional parameterless constructor which will use the default values. This makes it easier to use Kotlin with libraries such as Jackson or JPA that create class instances through parameterless constructors.  I copy that from [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors).Why  additional parameterless constructor can't be  generated?

Comment: @Cyrus because it don't have any **default** parameters.

Comment: Oh , I see. Thanks for your patience . There's always  a little difficult for me to understand English documents

Comment: @Cyrus I'm from China. my english is so bad too. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147697/discussion-between-cyrus-and-holi-java).

Comment: I was getting this "POJOS" error and another one about "getters" and was using the same "data class" format as was used in multiple example projects I created (I'm following a Kotlin Jetpack Compose course) which always worked. I'm coming from Java and am new to Kotlin. I would've NEVER figured this out, but I have the Java files from the old project I'm redoing in Kotlin/Jetpack and pasted those into Android Studio which converted them to Kotlin, thankfully.